# Converting mouse click position to a given scale

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

> You have a screen that display heart rate (of 1 hour - 60 minutes), How do you can to know which minute you are in, upon click on the screen? 
>   When you clicked on the screen you will get specific height and width.

This is what I've done: I created a form, and on the form i have docked PictureBox object. PictureBox object has a method that invoked by clicking on the PictureBox object. The method:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
    if (mouseEventArgs != null)
    {
        int widthPerMinute = (int)(mouseEventArgs.X / ((pictureBox1.Width + 1) / 60.0));
        MessageBox.Show((widthPerMinute).ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: How do you want to improve it? What is wrong with it as it is?

Comment: i looking for more elegant way to perform that.. if it's possible..

Comment: If you click halfway across the picture box, you are at relativePosX/boxWidth = .5; so wouldn't you then simply multiply .5 by 60 minutes to get minute 30? You are dividing by 60.

Comment: @Tim He's effectively got `x/(y/z)` which is of course `(x*z)/y` with `z = 60` in this instance.

Comment: You just got a +1, David. I did not know an **EventArgs** could simply be cast to **MouseEventArgs** like that. I'm using this!

Comment: Metthew, thank, jp2code, MouseEventArgs is inherited from EventArgs, and could to cast to MouseEventArgs and check if it's not null.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that cast to MouseEventArgs never succeeds, @jp2code. The Click event is *not* passed a MouseEventArgs instance, it's passed an EventArgs instance. You need to handle the MouseClick event if you want a MouseEventArgs. Then, yes, you can prototype the event handler method as receiving an EventArgs instance and then cast it to MouseEventArgs. But that's rather pointless.

Comment: @CodyGray The **EventArgs** passed to the `Click` event will indeed be **MouseEventArgs** if the click originated from a mouse (there are other ways to trigger `Click`.) However, since only mouse clicks are being processed in this example, `MouseClick` is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I misinterpreted what you were asking for my first reply (I'm leaving it at the end of this answer for reference).

I now think you're asking for a higher-level design for what you're doing.

If you are going to be developing the Heart Rate graph display further, then rather than just using a PictureBox you might want to write your own custom `Control` for it. That way you can encapsulate all the drawing logic nicely inside its implementation.

That would be a lot of learning though. Worth it if you think you might need to write more in the future.

MSDN introduction is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs3yhkh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But from the sound of it, it's an interview question or something, in which case you probably won't want to be spending this much time on it. ;)

---

My previous answer:

I wouldn't say there was a more "elegant" way, but I suppose you could make the code more readable by extracting into a separate method the logic that calculates the minute:

```
int minuteAtPictureBoxCoord(int x)
{
    double totalMinutes = 60;
    double minutesPerPixel = totalMinutes/(pictureBox1.Width+1);
    int minute = (int)(x*minutesPerPixel);
    return minute;
}
```

This is obviously a lot longer, but it is arguably a lot easier to see that the code is correct. (Although I'm not entirely sure about that +1 on `pictureBox1.Width+1` - I'm not sure that's correct; I copied it from your original code.)

It also simplifies the call site:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
    if (mouseEventArgs != null)
    {
        int minute = minuteAtPictureBoxCoord(mouseEventArgs.X);
        MessageBox.Show(minute.ToString());
    }
}
```

I think it's a little easier to tell at a glance what the code's up to.

Also, this makes it easier to change the calculations later if you change things like the the number of minutes displayed across the screen, or if you have multiple rows of heart rate data (then you'd need an X *and* a Y client coord).

One more thing: You should probably be using [`PictureBox.MouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) rather than just `Click()`. That way you actually get passed a `MouseEventArgs` so you don't need to do the cast. So it would become:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, mouseEventArgs e)
{
    int minute = minuteAtPictureBoxCoord(e.X);
    MessageBox.Show(minute.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: change `pictureBox1.Width+1` to `pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width` to get the width minus borders/margins/etc. and add 1 to `minute`, because the first minute would be `1`, not `0`, I believe.

Comment: Of course that i can doing it more readable..but i looking for more elegant way to perform that...yes, it's a interview question:) and i don't want to spend a time for that, for check my answer i doing that by picturebox.. but i like your response! Thank you! amm, the +1 it's because that for getting the minutes between 0-59.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett what the difference bewteen pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width and pictureBox1.Width?

Comment: @DavidMichaeli `.Width` will give you the size of the control including borders, scrollbars, and such, but `.ClientSize.Width` will give you the size inside the PictureBox. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize.aspx

Comment: @DavidMichaeli I tested this code out on a scratch project and with a 3px border on each side, the user could only click up to 6 pixels shy of the `.Width`, which could make for an inaccuracy in some cases

Comment: @DavidMichaeli I just read that it's for an interview question, so I don't think this difference matters to you, but for future references I think it's worthwhile to point out.